# Could not load type error in application page

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, applicationpage

I have created a application page for login functionality in sharepoint by following [this post](http://tomaszrabinski.pl/wordpress/2011/06/23/sharepoint-2010-custom-login-page/comment-page-1/#comment-1949).

But this giving me an error at inheriting the page. I have folder structure and .aspx file like below.
[image]
Did I done any mistake while giving the link to the .cs file in the application page?
After I deployed into my site, it is giving me error like below.
[image]
I am trying to resolve it from 2 hrs, but unable to find the solution. Can any one suggest me the way to do it please!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add
`<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>`

before
`<%@ Page ... %>`

Answer (score 1):

Add $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$ to your Inherits attribute

Instead of <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="YourPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="YourNamespace.YourPage"  %>

Use <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="YourPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="YourNamespace.YourPage,**$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$**"  %>

Answer (score 1):

This could also be happened when there are another reference to that assembly which didn't exist. To show the error, simply check Ha Doan answer.